# minimal polynomial of finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, prime-numbers, finite-fields, jordan-normal-form, characteristic-polynomial

$\frac{d}{d Y}: K[Y] \rightarrow K[Y], \quad \sum_{i \geq 0} a_{i} Y^{i} \mapsto \sum_{i \geq 0}(i+1) a_{i+1} Y^{i}$

$P_n =\[f \in K[Y] \mid \operatorname{deg}(f) \leq n]$ (this is a set)

$f=\left. \frac{d}{dY} \right|_{P_n} : P_n \rightarrow P_n$

Task:

Let $p$ be a prime number, let $K=\mathbb{F}_{p}$, the field with $p$ elements. Determine the minimal polynomial and the Jordan normal form of $f$.

Hint: The integers $k, r \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ defined by $n=kp+r$ and $r<p$ play a role!

**Problem/Approach:**

Unfortunately, I got pretty stuck here. The hint isn't that attractive looking. Thanks for any help!

Comment: My advice is that you begin by testing small cases. Like $p=2, n=3$ , $p=2,n=4$, $p=2, n=5$, and a few cases with $p=3$ or $5$. At least that way you collect some data and should see why the hint is relevant!

Comment: In the case where $p = 2$, there are two possible values for $r$: either $r = 0$ or $r = 1$.

When $p = 3$, there are three potential values for $r$: it can be $0$, $1$, or $2$.

Similarly, when $p = 5$, there are five potential values for $r$: it can be $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, or $4$.

From these observations, we can conclude that the number of distinct values that $r$ can take is exactly equal to $p$. If that observation is the correct way, how can I elaborate on that?